# Perl file processing optimization for regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading around more than million lines of million files.

But have tried to replace them using regular experssion for the certain strings .

My strings  are ( "tiger", "lion", "monkey") and replacing them by string "animal";

I have achived using regex substitution

```
$line =~ s/tiger/animal/g;
$line =~ s/lion/animal/g;
$line =~ s/monkey/animal/g;
```

When processed, it takes a lot of time during execution.

Here I want to understand why this is slow and how can I solve this problem in faster way?

I can't use any external modules to resolve this issue.

Comment: you just need to perform search and replace or you are doing any other task too?

Comment: i am doing other task also

Comment: the processing times is increased by 3 times  with that fix

Comment: Of which time dimensions do we speak here? Hours? Minutes?

Comment: Totally without this fix it take complete whole process by 2 hours 3 mins . But now it  takes more than 6 hours.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the surrounding code as well, and not just the substitutions.

Comment: What about running the process over night? ;-) Doesn't seem like a very time-critical task to me if it needs min. 2h.

Comment: What operating system?  What perl version?  Are those your actual regexes?  If not, what are they?  Or at least tell us if they are fixed strings (and how long) or a regex.

Comment: Also, you really need to show us more code - how you are looping over the files/lines, what else you are doing to $line.  Something else you are doing is having an impact here; there's no way that just doing those substitutions millions of times should take an extra four hours.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "precompiled form" of regexes:

```
my $regex = qr/\b(?:tiger|lion|monkey)\b/;

# in your loop:
$line ~= s/$regex/animal/g;
```

Note: the regex has been reduced to a single one, and a non capturing group `(?:...)` is used since there is no use for the captured text. Also, word anchors have been added (this means that `monkey` will be matched but not `greasemonkey`, for instance). Add `s?` before the last `\b` if you also want to replace plurals.

This, however, only takes care about the regex part: you also talk about other kinds of processing, maybe the entire process can be altered in some way so that it is eventually faster.

Comment: Doing some benchmarking here, and I did not notice any speed increase for using alternations and precompiling the regex. The opposite, in fact. However, I assume it has much to do with the input and regex.

Comment: @TLP I suspect the initial anchor has much to do with it, since in this case perl cannot apply first character optimization

Comment: Indeed. I did notice a benefit in using word boundaries though, which is to be expected. Surprisingly, though, using alternation vs using three different substitutions actually decreased speed by 70%.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this instead of 3 parts.

```
$line=~s/(tiger|monkey|lion)/animal/g;
```

Comment: The capturing parentheses reduce efficiency and are redundant in any case.

Comment: Also, dandeanimals are probably not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what "around more than million lines of million files" means, but suppose you have a million files, each with a million lines of, say, 40 characters each. That comes to 40TB of information.

If the data is on a hard disk, reading at, say, 50MB/s, this amount of data will take 40E12/50E6 = 800,000 seconds to read, or just over nine days.

If your program is completing in a few hours then you should be very grateful!